# MSBuild Design Practice for Custom Props/Targets

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-target, msbuild-15

I have a NuGet package I'm working on with custom props/targets files and am wondering about best practice for how to many Properties, Items, and Targets in terms of definition and overriding.

Is it better to have all properties directly in my `MyNuGetPackage.targets` file and don't use the `MyNuGetPackage.props` at all, like so?

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <UseMyTarget Condition="'$(Prop1)' == ''">true</UseMyTarget>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="MyTarget" Condition="'$(UseMyTarget)' == 'true'>
  ...
</Target>
```

or is it better practice to define `UseMyTarget` in the `.props` file, unconditionally and keep the target in the .targets file?

Both approaches break down if I need to catch a property that Microsoft or someone else sets a default value for. For example:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MyCustomOutputPath>$(OutputPath)/somethingelse</UseMyTarget>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If I define this in `.props`, `OutputPath` may not have been set yet...

On the other hand MANY authors seem to exclusively use `.targets` themselves...so am I better off just doing something like this for dependent things in my `.targets` and not bother with `.props` files?

```
<Project InitialTargets="InitializeDependentProperties">
  <Target Name="InitializeDependentProperties">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <MyCustomOutputPath>$(OutputPath)/somethingelse</UseMyTarget>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Microsoft's own  practices for their own MSBuild props/targets don't seem to follow any kind of standard/convention at all.

I DO want to allow consuming projects to be able to alter behavior of my `.props/.targets` by setting `Properties/Items/Targets` themselves.